# Validation failed for one or more entities In Angular Js

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I am working on MVC with Angular Js . I Added the ADO.NET Model to generate the essential classes. I am trying to register user by using Angular Js with ADO.NET Model Entities. I got two error when I click the submit button I got this error ....

```
angular.js:12701 POST http://localhost:53526/Register/AddUser 500 (Internal Server Error)...
```

When I click this link from Console Window from Google Chrome its saying ....

```
**Validation failed for one or more entities. See 'EntityValidationErrors' property for more details.
```

Here is my Local Class to Encrypt the user password..

```
public static class Utility
        {
            public static string Encryptpassword(string password)
            {
                string hashedPassword = BCrypt.Net.BCrypt.HashPassword(password, BCrypt.Net.BCrypt.GenerateSalt(12));
                return hashedPassword;
            }

            public static bool CheckPassword(string enteredPassword, string hashedPassword)
            {
                bool pwdHash = BCrypt.Net.BCrypt.Verify(enteredPassword, hashedPassword);
                return pwdHash;
            }
        }
    }
```

Here is my Register Controller Class...

```
 public class RegisterController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Register()
        {
            return View();
        }

        //To check that user entered is already present or not.  
        public bool CheckUser(string user)
        {
            bool Exists = false;
            using (HalifaxDatabaseEntities context = new HalifaxDatabaseEntities())
            {
                var uName = context.UserLogins.Where(x => x.UserName == user).ToList();
                if (uName.Count != 0)
                {
                    Exists = true;
                }
            }
            return Exists;
        }

        //For saving the user details in database table.          
        public string AddUser(UserLogin usr)
        {
            if (usr != null)
            {
                if (CheckUser(usr.UserName) == false)
                {
                    using (HalifaxDatabaseEntities context = new HalifaxDatabaseEntities())
                    {
                        UserLogin createUser = new UserLogin();
                        createUser.UserName = usr.UserName;
                        createUser.Firstname = usr.Firstname;
                        createUser.Lastname = usr.Lastname;
                        createUser.Email = usr.Email;
                        createUser.DateTimeCreated = DateTime.Now;
                        createUser.Password = Utility.Encryptpassword(usr.Password);
                        context.UserLogins.Add(createUser);
                        context.SaveChanges();
                    }
                    return "User created !";
                }
                else
                {
                    return "User already present !";
                }
            }
            else
            {
                return "Invalid Data !";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is Angular Js Code(Module.js)....

```
 var app = angular.module("myApp", [])
        .controller('Ctrl', ["$scope", 'myService', function ($scope, myService) {

            $scope.SaveUser = function () {
                $("#divLoading").show();
                var User = {
                    FName: $scope.fName,
                    LName: $scope.lName,
                    Email: $scope.uEmail,
                    Password: $scope.uPwd,
                    UserName: $scope.uName
                };

                var response = myService.AddUser(User);
                response.then(function (data) {
                    if (data.data == "1") {
                        $("#divLoading").hide();
                        clearFields();
                        alert("User Created !");
                        window.location.href = "/Register/Login";
                    }
                    else if (data.data == "-1") {
                        $("#divLoading").hide();
                        alert("user alraedy present !");
                    }
                    else {
                        $("#divLoading").hide();
                        clearFields();
                        alert("Invalid data entered !");
                    }
                });
            }

            function clearFields() {
                $scope.fName = "";
                $scope.lName = "";
                $scope.Email = "";
                $scope.Password = "";
                $scope.UserName = "";
            }

        }])
        .service("myService", function ($http) {

            this.AddUser = function (User) {
                var response = $http({
                    method: "post",
                    url: "/Register/AddUser",
                    data: JSON.stringify(User),
                    dataType: "json"
                });
                return response;
            }
        })
```

Here is MY HTML CODE ...

```
@{
    Layout = null;
}


<html ng-app="myApp">
<head>
    <title>Register</title>

    <script src="~/Scripts/angular.min.js"></script>
   <script src="~/Scripts/MyScript/Module.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.12.1.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap.js"></script>

    <link href="~/Content/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />


</head>
<body>

    <div class="container" ng-controller="Ctrl">
        <br />

        <div class="row">
            @*<img src="~/Content/Images/user.png" />*@<h4>Register User</h4>
            <hr />

            <br />
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <form name="userForm" novalidate>
                    <div class="form-horizontal">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-3" style="margin-left: 15px; color: #5bc0de;">
                                    First Name :
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="First Name" name="fName" ng-model="fName" required autofocus />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-3" style="margin-left: 15px; color: #5bc0de;">
                                    Last Name :
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Last Name" name="lName" ng-model="lName" required autofocus />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-3" style="margin-left: 15px; color: #5bc0de">
                                    Email :
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="User's Email" name="uEmail" ng-model="uEmail" required autofocus />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-3" style="margin-left: 15px; color: #5bc0de;">
                                    Username :
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" name="uName" ng-model="uName" required autofocus />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-3" style="margin-left: 15px; color: #5bc0de;">
                                    Password :
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" name="uPwd" ng-model="uPwd" required autofocus />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-4"></div>
                                <div class="col-md-3">
                                    <input type="button" value="Save" ng-click="SaveUser();" class="btn btn-success" />
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-3">
                                    @Html.ActionLink("Sign in", "Login", "Register", new { @class = "btn btn-info" })
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <div id="divLoading" style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; position: fixed; right: 0px; top: 0px; width: 100%; height: 100%; background-color: #666666; z-index: 30001; opacity: .8; filter: alpha(opacity=70); display: none">
                                        <p style="position: absolute; top: 30%; left: 45%; color: White;">
                                            please wait...<img src="~/Content/images/load.png">
                                        </p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is screen When I run the Application and click the submit button..[image: Click here to find the out put]

Here is screen shot when I click this link http://localhost:53526/Register/AddUser form Console Window..

[image: Click Here to see the result]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to pass it without JSON.stringify, also not need to mention data type

```
 .service("myService", function ($http) {

        this.AddUser = function (User) {
            var response = $http({
                method: "POST",
                url: "/Register/AddUser",
                data: User
            });
            return response;
        }
    })
```

Also apply this on your SaveChanges function to see the exact column name due to which you are facing this issue

```
 try
 {
  // Your code...
  // Could also be before try if you know the exception occurs in SaveChanges

  context.SaveChanges();
 }
 catch (DbEntityValidationException e)
 {
   foreach (var eve in e.EntityValidationErrors)
   {
    Console.WriteLine("Entity of type \"{0}\" in state \"{1}\" has the following validation errors:",
        eve.Entry.Entity.GetType().Name, eve.Entry.State);
     foreach (var ve in eve.ValidationErrors)
     {
        Console.WriteLine("- Property: \"{0}\", Error: \"{1}\"",
            ve.PropertyName, ve.ErrorMessage);
     }
   }
  throw;
}
```

Comment: try it now you just need to pass it this way without JSON.stringyfy

Comment: apply a break point on server side and check if you are recieving data on server

Comment: Server Error in '/' Application.

Validation failed for one or more entities. See 'EntityValidationErrors' property for more details.

Source Error: 


Line 47:                             createUser.Password = Utility.Encryptpassword(usr.Password);
Line 48:                             context.UserLogins.Add(createUser);
Line 49:                             context.SaveChanges();
Line 50:                         }
Line 51:                         return "User created !";

Comment: use the try catch block to check for which column you are facing validation error

Comment: context.SaveChanges();///Error on this line

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153029/discussion-between-ghulam-mohayudin-and-rasel).

Comment: Thanks its is working now after re generate ADO.NET Model Again